# Trying to reference a folder with my .properties and log4j files in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I don't want to put my .properties and log4j files in my /resources folder in my spring MVC appication because these will get put into the jar at compile time, and I want to be able to edit these files on my server when I deploy my application.

So I created a folder and dropped my log4j, *.properties files, and my spring-context.xml file in it.

I have a maven multi project, and my folders look like:

```
/myapp-persists
/myapp-web
/src/main/conf
```

The /src/main/conf has my property files, so in IntelliJ I went to the myapp-web module and added a 'jar or directories' dependancy, pointed to that folder and chose 'classes'.

It didn't work, my files were not picked up and starting the server resulted in a crash, the property files were not detected.

What am I doing wrong here?

It seems me doing this via intelliJ is going to cause my maven builds to fail then right?  I really don't want to create a separate maven project for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the context menu on `/src/main/conf` and choose *Directory : Add as Source*. In the preferences you should set *keep source folders* in the maven settings (not really sure about the naming of the menu/settings - no idea at hand, sorry). The jar dependency is not needed.